# Yet another AMD GPU DKMS build error, Ubuntu 18.04 on Azure, Linux 5.3

Tags: dkms, opencl, amdgpu-pro, azure

So, I've downloaded the AMD GPU (OpenCL) drivers (after a painful awaiting) for Ubuntu 18.04 on Azure for benchmark purposes (namely, mining), using the [NVv4 series](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-nvv4-azure-virtual-machines-for-gpu-visualization-workloads/) VMs (virtualized [AMD Radeon Instinct MI25](https://www.amd.com/en/products/professional-graphics/instinct-mi25) on the [AMD EPYC 7002](https://www.amd.com/es/processors/epyc-7002-series)). It was unsuccesfull (gminer can't find the device), but this is another story.

The issue I come here is a building issue (that may happen to enyone else under similar scenarios). DKMS module builds successfully under Linux 4.15, but fails under Linux 5.3. [Here are the logs](https://gist.github.com/Amitie10g/9685aeddff35309644eeafc3ff756a2f).

I already given up for trying the NVv4 series on Linux, as them seems to be more for desktop environments, but I tell this to get some feedback.

Finally, remember that mining on Azure is very expensive, specially for the lack of the more affordable Tesla T4 (found in AWS and Google Cloud).